# pymongo how aggregate null and false

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Good day!

I need to use an aggregate function in python.

1. On the mongo command line, the command that I needed looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('vhs').aggregate([{$match:{$or:[{"idSimple":""},{"idSimple":null},{"idSimple":{$exists:true}}]}},{$count:"count"}])
```

Tried it in python so

```
pipeline = [{"$match":{"$or":[{"idSimple":""},{"idSimple":"null"},{"idSimple":{"$exists":"false"}}]}},{"$count":"count"}]
```

and so

```
pipeline = [{"$match":{"$or":[{"idSimple":""},{"idSimple":None},{"idSimple":{"$exists":False}}]}},{"$count":"count"}]
```

works clumsily, counts all documents, as if aggregation does not work

2. Also, due to the peculiarities of displaying empty values, the count does not count. I would like to output 0 in case of an empty response.

But that doesn't work correctly. Output in the end

```
[]
```

I tried so

```
        result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
        if result is None:
                result = {'count': 0}
        return result
```

But don't work for me.

3. How do work filter in aggregate function with regular expression?
   I tried so

```
pipeline = [{"$match":{"$or":[{"idSimple":'/1/'},{"idSimple":"null"},{"idSimple":{"$exists":"false"}}]}},{"$count":"count"}]
```

But didn't work

My data, for example,

```
Pe1DXd
TlCF7e
d0zLbe
sIFhph
dmwGnd
VCbpYg
8Hdpjd
Bevpih
CNoGgg
ajlDKg
u3f7if
0K2ZZe
5oRbGd
X0rNMd
jGib9g
5eYlTe
M5ugTd
UVVw9f
tn4VAh
Crb48d
FvGDee
EfveIe
MfShqf
CPVkrh
QH4zGf
Ogobpg
nCmyig
eVfijf
```

But, this, for example. There are many documents with the number '1' in the database.

I add full my script below

```
import pymongo
import bson
import urllib.parse

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = "27017"
user = "MYUSER"
password = "MYPASSWD"
dbname = "MYDB"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(f'mongodb://{urllib.parse.quote_plus(user)}:{urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)}@{host}:{port}/admin')
db = client[dbname]
#db = client.get_database()
collection_vls = db['vls']

def aggregate_documents(collection, pipeline):
        result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
        if result == []:
                result = {'count': 0}
        return result

pipeline = [{"$match":{"$or":[{"idSimple":'/1/'},{"idSimple":None},{"idSimple":{"$exists":False}}]}},{"$count":"count"}]
result = aggregate_documents(collection_vls, pipeline)
print(list(result))
```

Comment: In `mongosh` you have `"idSimple":{$exists:true}`, but with `pymongo` you show `"idSimple":{"$exists":False}`.  Is one of these incorrect?

Comment: I tried pipeline = [{"$match":{"$or":[{"idSimple":""},{"idSimple":None},{"idSimple":{"$exists":False}}]}},{"$count":"count"}] . But this option counts all existing documents. But he must be empty, i.e. 0 documents.

Comment: Would you edit your question and include a sample of your documents?

Comment: In your questions's _"My data..."_, are these the values of `"idSimple"`?  Do some documents have `"idSimple": null`, `"idSimple": ""`, and some with no `"idSimple"` field?

Comment: Аt the moment, not. That's why I can't show you. And this is not all data. But this is just for control, so that such documents do not accidentally appear.

Comment: Using `pipeline = [{"$match":{"$or":[{"idSimple":""},{"idSimple":None},{"idSimple":{"$exists":False}}]}},{"$count":"count"}]`, like you show, should work (if I understand your intenetions). And if you change `if result is None:` to `if result == []:` then you should get the ultimate `result` you are looking for.  In addition, if you create an index on `idSimple` then the query should be fairly performant.

Comment: No, it does not work. Gives out all the time []
Maybe something else is wrong? Here is the full script listing.

Comment: How about with `if list(result) == []:`?

Comment: ... Hmmm, `list(result)` here may not be a good idea.  I can't test right now, but this may exhaust the cursor and create problems when `result` is returned.  It would probably be better for `aggregate_documents` to just return the [`CommandCursor`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) or perhaps the `list` of that, and then qualify the result with whatever you want after the call to `aggregate_documents`.

Comment: Yes if list(result) == [] work. But who came up with all these complications? It's just a nightmare. It seems that it started to work and I wanted to figure it out further, already for each of the values ​​of the idSimple field, how it [] appears again in the output, but 'if list(result) == []' no longer works on it. In general, hands down. And I'm stuck in one place.

Comment: It can be confusing.  Some things with database retrievals are _"lazy"_ in that the _"cursor"_ only provides the returned data when required, like when you convert it to a `list`.  After the cursor is exhausted, assigning it to another variable probably won't give you what you want.